# I want to read this specific csv file, using Matlab. I used textscan but I failed

Tags: matlab, csv

csv file:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
20170217,64.470001,64.690002,64.300003,64.620003,21234600,64.620003
20170216,64.739998,65.239998,64.440002,64.519997,20524700,64.519997
```

I used this:

```
fileID = fopen('table.csv');
C = textscan(fileID,'%s %f %f %f %f %d %f','Delimiter',',');
fclose(fileID);
celldisp(C)
```

but It does not read anything.

Comment: Why not just use `readtable`?

Comment: You may need to skip the first line before using `textscan`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `csvread` function to read a *csv* file.

```
m=csvread('table.csv',1,0)
```

The values are stored in a matrix.

Since your file has an header line, you have to specify, in the call, to start reading from the second row of the file.

You can do it by adding two parameters in the call:

- the first defines the row from which to start reading (notice that the index is *zero base*)
- the second defines the column from which to start (in the case of the example, from the first)

If, nevertheless, you want to use `textscan`, you have to modify your code as follows:

```
fileID = fopen('table.csv');
% C = textscan(fileID,'%s %f %f %f %f %d %f','Delimiter',',');
C1 = textscan(fileID,'%s',2);

C2 = textscan(fileID,'%d%f%f%f%f%d%f','delimiter',',')
fclose(fileID);
```

You have to call `textscan` twice:

- the first time ro read the first row (the header)
- the second time to read the data

Notice in the first call the third parameter in the call: it specifies that the `format` (`%s`) has to be used twice.

This because in your header row the last word is separated by a `space`.

Once you've read the header row, you call `textscan` for the again to read the numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

CSV is reading by `xlsread('File');`
if it is reading nan so do

```
[num text all]=xlsread('file');
```

and do for loops on text output